# Sqlite: select top x values for n users

Tags: sqlite

I've got a Sqlite DB table (test) that looks like the sample:

```
User Score
```

User looks like User1, User2...User 20

Score is an integer.

Example:

```
User1 204
User2 5555
User6 102
etc.
```

How it is it possible to select, let's say, 3 top values for each existing user ordered by score? For example:

```
User1 4344
User1 4000
User1 2330
User2 2300
User2 1000
User2 300
User3 555
User3 100
User3 10
User4 2033
...
```

This gives me only top 3 of all users.

```
  SELECT user, score FROM test ORDER BY score DESC limit 3
```

This gives me all users but only one top value.

```
  SELECT user, score FROM test GROUP BY user ORDER BY score DESC
```

The one and the only solution I've found so far is to add all the users to a list and to use a loop (I work with Python). Each time one user is analyzed.
But I'm curious if it's possible to do that without the loop and only by Sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window functions are your friend (requires 3.25 or newer):

```
SELECT user, score
FROM (SELECT user, score,
             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY score DESC) AS rn
       FROM test)
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY user, score DESC;
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. Seems like it works :) Have to rename users as User01, User02 to sort correctly but that's not a big deal.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create another table to store the output result, in my example I called it **outputresult(user, score)**:

```
Declare     @duser nvarchar(30)
Declare     @duser2 nvarchar(30)
Declare     @dscore int

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
select distinct [user] from TOP3s



OPEN cur1

FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @duser

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0 

BEGIN

Declare cur2 Cursor FOR
select top (3) [user], score from TOP3s where [user] = @duser order by [user], score desc
OPEN cur2

fetch next from cur2 into @duser2, @dscore

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0 

begin

insert into outputresult values(@duser2, @dscore)

fetch next from cur2 into @duser2, @dscore

end

close cur2
deallocate cur2


FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @duser

end

close cur1

Deallocate cur1


--you can run this query to check the output:
select * from outputresult
```

Comment: Seems like Sqlite doesn't support such things as Declare but it's possible to create some temporary table in memory. OK, thanks, I've thought about such idea but I hoped that there might be some tricky query to do that easily.

Comment: you can take it further than that...you can create a table to store the variables I declared with the **declare** statement, but I am not sure you wanna go there.

Comment: That's not remotely valid sqlite syntax.